# Adding dynamic values to System.Data.Linq.Mapping

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have the table `Foo` containing `ID int`, `FirstName varchar(50)` and `Address varchar(50)`.

I have the following `Class`:

```
Imports System.Data.Linq.Mapping
<Table(Name:="Foo")> _
Public Class FooCollection
    <Column()> Public ID As Integer
    <Column(Name:="FirstName")> Public Name As String
    <Column()> Public Address As String
Public Bar As String
    Public Baz As String
End Class
```

I want to return values that are not in the database but are generated on the fly. One is a reformatting of data that we do not want to store as a duplicate in the database. The other is information we want to return at the same time but is not database-driven.

I want `FooCollection.Bar` to return `Name & " " & ID & " " & Address` and
I want `FooCollection.Baz` to return something external, say a fixed string like `Hello World` for demonstration.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: @Bugs Thanks for the reformat. Certainly looks cleaner now :)

I added some code that I forgot when I first posted the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out - Use properties to return the non-database values.